# Why would a url_for helper in Rails fail when re-rendering a partial from a different controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a page with a bunch of widgets that has content that is primarily rendered by the CustomerController. However, there is this other controller called the DigitalItemController that is used to process business logic regarding changes to a customer's item. I have a form that is used to upload a file that is to be handled by a method in DigitalItemController via POST. The form is located in a partial that is named :customer_assets because it contains customer files they have uploaded. This same widget has a table of the files already uploaded with links to them.

The problem I am having is that since CustomerController usually does the rendering, it renders my partial just fine with no complaints. However, when I have the user submit a file for uploading, it calls a method in my DigitalItemController, where the last line of it says to render the partial. When it hits that line, I get an ActionController::RoutingError as it tries to render the partial. The line it doesn't like is:

```
%td= link_to(item_file.storage_info.s3_key,
          url_for(:controller => :data, 
            :action => :get_storage_information_link,
            :digital_item_id => item.digital_item_id, 
            :digital_storage_id => item_file.digital_storage_id))
```

I didn't think there would be a problem since the DataController is explicitly used here. It should know I want to just re-render the partial like it did before. However, I get this instead:

```
No route matches {:digital_storage_id=>#####, :action=>"get_storage_information_link", :digital_item_id=>#######, :controller=>"data"}
```

Obviously ID numbers here have been censored out, just in case. All I need to do is have that method in the DigitalItemController handle the file upload and then re-render the partial so that the widget shows the correct and up-to-date data. It just seems odd to me that it renders just fine when it is rendered normally, but as soon as the file is submitted, it throws routing errors.

What is the way to fix this?

Comment: I actually came across similar problem like a day ago, and couldn't find any reason why it wasn't working. I had correct route and everything.

Comment: try remove your `url_for`, it means just use `link_to(item_file.storage_info.s3_key,
          :controller => :data, 
            :action => :get_storage_information_link,
            :digital_item_id => item.digital_item_id, 
            :digital_storage_id => item_file.digital_storage_id)`, it's already relies on `url_for`.